# How to equalise two different Dataframe column into same size

Tags: python, pandas

I have two different dataFrame columns and they are not in equal size, what is the best way to get it done...Thanks in advnace

for example: -

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns = list('ab'))
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,2), columns = list('ab'))
    df2 = df2['b'].values
    n = len(df1) #100
    xi = np.linspace(0, n, df2)
```

I can't convert the array to a float value, any suggestions, pointer helps a lot!

Comment: So you want to resize df2 to 100 rows? Do you want nan values?

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, for swift response, yes please I want to make it 100 rows (only values, not Nan values), thank you so much...

Comment: But how do want these values to be filled? You have random values in your sample, are you wanting random values to fill the additional 50 rows, are you planning on interpolation but that only makes sense for missing values in between rows? Please update your post with additional information

Comment: The linspace function you tried creates a new array of `num` length using the `start` `stop` values, this would over write your values if you wanted to create a new 100 element array, see `np.linspace(0,n, num=100)` with equally spaced values

Comment: Thanks, basically I have two CSV files with reading, one with 100 reading and second one with 50 reading, so I am trying to fit both graph in same plot (stretching the smaller one to the size of bigger one) for comparison so I am trying to convert both DataFrame into same size (as per requirements). Thanks

Comment: You've still not explained how the values should be inserted for the smaller df

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking linespace would take care that, [figure](http://i.imgur.com/fz1A97B.png), if I insert zero will lose the shape and also if I add random numbers also lose the shape. If not linespace please suggest me what would be the best way to achieve. Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know what that figure really shows but you could just append a new df: `df2 = df2.append(df2, ignore_index=True)` or a new df: `df2.append(pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,2), columns = list('ab')), ignore_index=True)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, will work on that and see what do I get, thanks again...

Comment: If I do df2 = df2.append(df2, ignore_index=True), the bin values are repeating after 50th position, I just want to stretch the signal rather than repeating the signal. thank you so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments, I believe you're asking the wrong question. You say 
*I am trying to fit both graph in same plot (stretching the smaller one to the size of bigger one) for comparison so I am trying to convert both DataFrame into same size (as per requirements).*

What I would try to do instead is to have the second values *spread over the column*. As long as you use lines instead of dots to plot the values, there will be no visual difference.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2), columns = list('ab'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(50,2), columns = list('ab'))
x = len(df1)/len(df2)
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', 'b'], index=df1.index)
df3[::x] = df2.values

In[78]: df3.head()
Out[78]: 
           a          b
0  0.3328085  0.7470998
1        NaN        NaN
2  0.8862908  0.5316886
3        NaN        NaN
4  0.7480417  0.7225618
```

Now you can do stuff as

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df3], axis=1)
df.plot()
```

Comment: I got your golden logic, thanks, 1. when I try the same code it shoots up an error "TypeError: the slice step value [2.0] is not a proper indexer for this index type (Int64Index)" -- 2. Do I have to change index=df1.index (df1 as reference) instead of index=df.index if I understood correctly? thanks a lot

Comment: I guess that you have some float magic activated. Try `df3[::int(x)]`.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, It's working finally, thank you so much for your support. For some reason I could able the second plot, may be it is not doing with Nan values, is that correct. I am very sorry keep bothering you, thanks.